# iOS simulator screen size

Tags: ios, xcode

It is just 2days to start iOS programming.

So I'm very beginner in this area.

[image]
<--This image is in iOS simulator. As you see right part is cropped.

[image]
<--This image is original UI.

I don't know why some parts have gone.

I am using MacBook Pro 2011 with Yosemite OS and brand-new XCode.

I tried cmd+1, cmd+2, cmd+3.

Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's hard to be sure but it looks as if you have not setup any constraints (so you're not using Auto-Layout). You need to add constraints to the label so that it "understands" what it's supposed to do. I strongly suggest you look at a tutorial (like: http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1) as this is basic stuff. Look in the Apple docs for Autolayout, constraints and size classes and learn about them. Don't switch them off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to file inspector and uncheck the "use size classes" option, this is due to newly introduced size class feature to support all devices in ios 8

Answer (score 1):

The new user interface works with all sizes of devices at once. The default size is 600x600 as you are seeing. When you simulate, is uses autolayout and constraints to arrange objects for the desired screen, aka an iPhone.
If you want to place the label in the center of the screen, Ctrl+drag from the label to the background, release mouse and buttons and the constraints options will appear. Click Center Horizontally in Container and Center Vertically in Container.
Run again. It will be centered.

Best regards

Comment: When I drag the label with Ctrl, label go back to former place.

Comment: First press Ctrl. Then drag from the label in the middle of the screen 1 inch to the top. Release mouse and Ctrl. Message should appear.

Answer (score 0):

Select your view controller and find size inspector, Change fixed to freeform and give whatever size you want

Answer (score 0):

I had a closely related question, and Mehul Thakkar's answer helped me to get where I needed to be, but I'm adding a new answer to flesh out both the question and answer a bit.

I was working on an iPhone app for iOS 8 that was shrinking the interface on larger screens to the size of the iPhone 4s. I don't use storyboards or Interface Builder nib/xib files at all, and do everything programmatically; for iOS 7 and earlier, I didn't bother making an explicit launch screen as my UI was simple enough that it loaded very quickly and a launch screen wasn't necessary.

Anyway, after finding this page and poking around a bit, it appears that creating a launch screen storyboard or nib/xib is now necessary on iOS 8, if you want your application to run at the correct size? (At least, I couldn't find any other way to coerce Xcode to do it in the project settings or whatnot.)

To do this, I created a new launch screen .xib file, unchecked "Use Size Classes" in the "Interface Builder Document" section of the File Inspector of that .xib file, and set the "Launch Screen File" under the General tab of my target settings to use that .xib. After that, the app ran at full screen size again.

This works for me and I guess I don't mind putting in a few minutes to turn the .xib file into a proper splash screen, but I'd be interested in hearing if there are other/better ways of making things work in iOS 8 and beyond, for those of us who hate our lovely code being tainted by the presence of those nasty storyboards/nibs/xibs...